# AutoMapper from list in DTO to individual object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the DTO below in which I need to map it to a flat view model, the idea is that some of the properties that come through from the request are shared, but there could be a list of names that come through.

```
public class ShinyDTO
{
    public List<UserDetails> Users { get; set; }

    public string SharedPropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string SharedPropertyTwo { get; set; }
 }

public class UserDetails
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public class MyRealClass
{
    public string SharedPropertyOne {get;set;}
    public string SharedPropertyTwo {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Forename {get;set;}
    public string Surname {get;set;}
}

//This will map all the shared properties
MyRealClass request = Mapper.Map<MyRealClass>(dto);

foreach (var record in dto.Users){
     //This bit overwrites the properties set above and then I only have the properties set for Forename, Surname, etc...

     request = Mapper.Map<MyRealClass>(record);
}
```

I need to map this into a list of MyRealClass. I've tried creating seperate mappings and then looping it within a foreach, but this kept removing the initial attributes.

I've also tried setting up the second mapping to ignore the properties set above and I couldn't get this working, it was still overwriting the properties.

```
var autoMapperConfiguration = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
autoMapperConfiguration
            .CreateMap<MyRealClass, UserDetails>()
            .ForMember(c => c.SharedPropertyOne, d => d.Ignore())
            .ForMember(c => c.SharedPropertyTwo, d => d.Ignore());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close, but your question states:

> I need to map this into a list of `MyRealClass`

... and your attempted mapping maps `MyRealClass` to `UserDetails`. It seems like you actually want a map from `UserDetails` to `MyRealClass` instead.

Anyway, here's one way to accomplish this:

```
var autoMapperConfiguration = new MapperConfigurationExpression();

autoMapperConfiguration.CreateMap<UserDetails, MyRealClass>();
autoMapperConfiguration.CreateMap<ShinyDTO, MyRealClass>();

var results = new List<MyRealClass>();

foreach(var record in dto.Users) {
    var mapped = Mapper.Map<MyRealClass>(dto);
    Mapper.Map(record, mapped);

    results.Add(mapped);
}
```

Here, the second `Mapper.Map` call maps `record` onto `mapped`, and it should not overwrite the values that have already been mapped over by the mapping from `ShinyDTO` to `MyRealClass`.

You could also get fancy and do all of this in a `ConstructUsing` call, but this seems clearer to me.

Comment: This what what I needed - you were right about the mapping, that was just something I'd typed manually though - hadn't copied and pasted.

I was trying to do  mapped = Mapper.Map(record, mapped); to reassign it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map between `UserDetails` and `IEnumerable<MyRealClass>`.

```
var autoMapperConfiguration = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
autoMapperConfiguration
            .CreateMap<IEnumerable<MyRealClass>, UserDetails>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.SharedPropertyOne, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.get(0).SharedPropertyOne)); //you can check if the list is empty
            .ForMember(dest => dest.SharedPropertyTwo, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.get(0).SharedPropertyTwo)); //you can check if the list is empty
            .AfterMap((src,dest) => //src is a list type
                 {
                      foreach(MyRealClass myrealclass in src)
                           dest.Users.add(new UserDetails(){
                                           Title = myrealclass.Title,
                                           Forename = myrealclass.Forename,
                                           Surname = myrealclass.Surname

                                     });
                 });
```